# Excel formula to return abcd from a cell containing [ab]{xy}[cd]{zw}

Tags: worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

An excel file contains some cells with text in this format: [ab]{xy}[cd]{zw}, where there can be between 0 and 10 `[whatever]{whatever2}` sequences.

I would like a formula to get all the text inside the `[]` brackets. For example for the cell:

`[ab]{cd}[de]{fg}[hi]{jk}` it should return `abdehi`.

This cell could also contain text in the format `a[bc]{de}f`, `a[bc]{de}[fg]{hi}j` or `a[bc]{de}fg[hi]{jk}l` in which I would expect the output to be `abcf` and `abcfgj`, `abcfghil` respectively.

Usually I would use regex, but the regex formulas for excel don't allow me to do this as far as I know.

Currently using google spreadsheets if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN("",1,IF(ISODD(SEQUENCE(1,2*COUNTA(SPLIT(A1,"[")))),SPLIT(A1,"[]"),"")))`

Comment: It works! But I forgot to say that sometimes the cell might contain some text in front such as: `x[ab]{cd}`, in that case how would it be?

Comment: I have updated the question to show this.

Answer (score 0):

For those useing Excel 365, you can use the formula:

```
=LET(x,TEXTSPLIT(A1,"[",,TRUE,1),CONCAT(TEXTSPLIT(FILTER(x,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("]",x))),"]")))
```

[image]